# Using ETL for Aggregations

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

I haven't been able to find any direct answers, so I thought I'd ask here.

Can ETL, say for example AWS Glue, be used to perform aggregations to lower the resolution of data to AVG, MIN, MAX, etc over arbitrary time ranges?

e.g. - Given 2000+ data points of outside temperature in the past month, use an ETL job to lower that resolution to 30 data points of daily averages over the past month. (actual use case of such data aside, just an example).

The idea is to perform aggregations to lower the resolution of data to make charts, graphs, etc display long time ranges of large data sets more quickly, as we don't need every individual data point that we must then dynamically aggregate on the fly for these charts and graphs.

My research so far only suggests that ETL be used for 1 to 1 transformations of data, not 1000 to 1. It seems ETL is used more for transforming data to appropriate structure to store in a db, and not for aggregating over large data sets.

Could I use ETL to solve my aggregation needs? This will be on a very large scale, implemented with AWS and Python.

Comment: I can't comment about the applicability of AWS to a task like this but would like to mention that ETL can include aggregation of data rows which is often accomplish using SQL GROUP BY. If you're not obliged to use AWS then there are various pure-Python solutions that might work, obviously depending on the details of your situation.

Comment: ETL is a generic concept, not a specific solution. It's much broader than your research has turned up. Maintaining aggregate tables and dimension tables in data warehouses are common ETL scenarios and there's very little 1:1 about either of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'T' in ETL stands for 'Transform', and aggregation is one of most common ones performed. Briefly speaking: yes, ETL can do this for you. The rest depends on specific needs. Do you need any drill-down? Increasing resolution on zoom perhaps? This would affect the whole design, but in general preparing your data for presentation layer is exactly what ETL is used for.